# When a button passes through a specified Y value, all the other buttons falling also disappear with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make multiple buttons fall down the screen all at once, at different speeds. But when I have my `if` statement check if it passed through the value, all the other buttons disappear with it. I'm also incrementing the score to go -1 each time a button passes through the Y value. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
- (void)b1Fall
{
b1.center = CGPointMake(b1.center.x, b1.center.y+6);

if (b1.center.y >= 506) {
    [self updateScore];
    b1.center = CGPointMake(44, 11);
  }
}

- (void)b2Fall
{
b2.center = CGPointMake(b2.center.x, b2.center.y+7);

if (b2.center.y >= 506) {
    [self updateScore];
    b2.center = CGPointMake(160, 11);
}
}

- (void)b3Fall
{
b3.center = CGPointMake(b3.center.x, b3.center.y+8);

if (b3.center.y >= 506) {
    [self updateScore];
    b3.center = CGPointMake(276, 11);
  }
}

- (void)updateScore
{
healthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [healthLabel.text intValue]-1];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// REMOVE AFTER TESTING    
b1Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(b1Fall) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
b2Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(b2Fall) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
b2Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(b3Fall) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
}
```

Comment: It is interesting that setting the text to the healthLabel is causing a reset of the positions. If you have Autolayout setup in the XIB, try turning it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1.) Put these animations in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad - you want the animation to begin when the user is actually looking at the buttons, not when the view is loaded into memory, where the user may not be able to see it (viewDidLoad).

2.) Don't use NSTimer for animations, use this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{


                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        // loop your animation here.

                     }];
```

3.) If you want to make a game, I don't recommend using this approach. All animations using UIKit are going to perform on the main thread and block the user flow. What you want is a framework like Cocos2D where the animations are doing in the GPU and ASYNC game logic is readily supported. UIKit isn't a good choice for game development in general.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try Cocos2D instead. I'd accept your answer as the answer, but I feel as if it'd be misleading, and others might think I used the code for the problem. Can you reply with an answer saying to use Cocos, and I'll accept. Thanks man. :)